# How to set a objectId property in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema named as Message like below;

```
Message = new Schema({
    id: Number,
    sender: ObjectId,
    receiver: ObjectId,
    date: Date,
    content: String,
    type: Number
});
```

And a User schema like below;

```
User = new Schema({
 id: Number,
 username: String,
 isOnline: Boolean
});
```

I would like to set the sender and receiver properties of message item when a new message is received. When a message is received I am creating a new Message document and setting its properties. But I do not know how to set sender and receiver properties (which should be a reference to an entity in User document). The code I'm using is like below. You can judge the code as much as you want, that's what I would like to. I do not know the right way to get rid of it. But it seems that this is not the one. When I'm using the code below I could not see the sender and receiver properties are set. I think that it could be because findOne is async (I do not know if it is).

```
var m = new Message();
m.content = messageData.text;
m.id = messageId;
User.findOne({id: socket.userId}, function (e, o) {
  m.sender = o;
});

User.findOne({id: messageData.userId}, function (e, o) {
  m.receiver = o;
});

m.save(function (e) {
  if (!e) {
    console.log("message is saved to the mongodb...");
  }
});
```

It would be great that if you can tell the right way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. You are correct that `findOne` is async. You just need to get a handle on their callbacks and save the message after they both respond. Here is a typical pattern you can use:

```
var m = new Message();
m.content = messageData.text;
m.id = messageId;
User.findOne({id: socket.userId}, function (e, o) {
  if (e) return handleError(e); // assuming you want to handle errors somehow
  m.sender = o;
  m.sender && m.receiver && save();
});

User.findOne({id: messageData.userId}, function (e, o) {
  if (e) return handleError(e); // assuming you want to handle errors somehow
  m.receiver = o;
  m.sender && m.receiver && save();
});

function save () {
  m.save(function (e) {
    if (e) return handleError(e);
    console.log("message is saved to the mongodb...");
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I understand your approach. But the method seem a little confusing. Is this the only way to do this? Because there could be some more fields like sender and receiver. Should I do the same for each of them? Isn't there any and method like m.sender = new User ({id: socket.userId}); ?

Comment: As I have researched a little more, I have found an async plugin for node.js which does the same that you have suggested with some other futures. Guess, it does not seem any other solution around there.